# Does EvoPdf HtmlToPdfConverter supports emoji character?

Tags: c#, emoji, evopdf

Unfortunately the [EvoPdf docu](https://www.evopdf.com/html-to-pdf-converter.aspx) doesn't give a statement if emojis are supported in Html -> Pdf conversion.

I've tried:

```
var html = "<html><body>123</body></html>";

var htmlToPdfConverter = new HtmlToPdfConverter();

var fileName = $@"c:\temp\emojies\test_{DateTime.Now:HHMMddhhmmss}.pdf";

htmlToPdfConverter.ConvertHtmlToFile(html, null, fileName);

Process.Start(fileName);
```

The resulting pdf just contains "123" and nothing more (no ? for unsupported characters).

Can anyone confirm that EvoPdf doesn't support emojis in pdf conversion?

What bits are relevant for emoji support in this context? Is it the used font-type, the used encoding or something else?

Comment: Personally I've experienced nothing but pain with third-party WebKit-based HTML-to-PDF based converters like EvoPDF, Qt's and wkhtmltopdf. Instead I recommend using Chrome in headless mode with Puppeteer instead (Puppeteer is Google's official automation system for Chrome). There are Puppeteer libraries for .NET:  e.g. https://www.puppeteersharp.com/examples/index.html

Comment: @Dai: Interesting approach! Didn't know of this library! Right now that would cause too much refactoring, but mid-term this could be a nice alternative to evopdf (as we have some other issues with this component)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The NE (New Edition) version you can download from https://www.evopdf.com/download.aspx supports the emojis from your example.

Comment: I can confirm that the NE Version supports emojis. @EvoPdf: Thanks! But there is still nothing in the docu about emoji support...